# Unable to open the kubernetes dashboard in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I created kubernetes cluster in my Azure resource group using **Azure Kubernetes Service** and login into cluster with the help of resource group credentials through  Azure CLI. I could opened the kubernetes dashboard successfully for the first time.  After that i deleted my resource group and other resource groups which are defaultly created along with kubernetes cluster. I created resource group and kubernetes cluster one more time in my azure account. i am trying to open the kubernetes dashboard next time, getting error like 8001 port not open. I tried with proxy port-forwarding, but i don't have idea how to hit the dashboard url with different port?.

Could anybody suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to delete your kubernetes config and pull new one with `az aks get-credentials` or whatever you are using, because you are probably still using config from the previous cluster (hint: it wont work because its a different cluster).

you can do that by deleting this file: `~/.kube/config` and pull the new one and try `kubectl get nodes`. if that works try the port-forward. It is not port related. something is wrong with your config\az cli

ok, I recall in the previous question you mentioned you started using RBAC, you need to add cluster role to the dashboard:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-dashboard#for-rbac-enabled-clusters

Comment: I created new kubernetes cluster in new resource group.i trying to open the kubernetes dashboard using command `az aks browse --resource-group DevOps-kubernetes --name nodecluster`. previously i did proxy port-forwarding on 9090. I deleted that cluster along with all resource groups. Now i trying with new and i am getting the error like `{"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8001}`.How could i hit the dashboard url with 9090?

Comment: check updated answer, it might help. but this error is a bit weird, doesnt look like something wrong with the dashboard, check spelling, check you are in proper subscription etc

Comment: I tried with the command what you suggested. still i am getting the same error. I hope this issue is because of port. How could i kill the process running on ports in Azure Kubernetes?

Comment: delete old kubernetes config (usually under `~/.kube/config`) and pull the new one and try `kubectl get nodes`. if that works try the port-forward. Its not port related. something is wrong with your config\az cli

Comment: i don't have idea on that. Can you please guided me?

Comment: how to delete a file?

Comment: rm -rf <file-name>. This command i used every time for deleting file?

Comment: yeah, you could do that

Comment: i did that.Again how could i pull the new kube config file? or Is it generated automatically?

Comment: they way you've done it previously, or just try `az aks browse` at this point

Comment: can you please set  it as answer.`delete old kubernetes config (usually under ~/.kube/config) and pull the new one and try kubectl get nodes. if that works try the port-forward. It is not port related. something is wrong with your config\az cli`. i can view my dashboard. Thank you